# What can I do about "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

I have a little shell script that simply starts up a Java program. It is installed somewhere deep in the hierarchy, so I don't want to add its containing folder too my path. So I put a symbolic link into `/usr/bin`. But when I try to run it, I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/asadmin: cannot execute binary file
```

I checked the permissions, and both the symbolic link and the shell script are executable. What can I do about this?

Comment: could be something wrong with your `asadmin` shell script.  why does bash think it's a binary?

Comment: @jdigital there is a shebang `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: what does `file asadmin` return (using the actual path for asadmin)?

Comment: @jdigital `POSIX shell script text executable`

Comment: what does `ls -l /usr/bin/asadmin` show?

Comment: do you invoke any binary executables from within you script? su perhaps?

Comment: This error message means bash does not recognize the file as a shell script or as a compatible executable file. If it is a shell script:, could you post the first few lines (and make sure to copy them exactly. E.g. `#!/bin/bash^M`. If it is a binary, check if it is a x64 binary and that you are not running an x32/x86 OS (Not sure if there still is a 32 bit OS X version, but that would cause the same error).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a little shell script that simply starts up a Java program.

Within your script, are you invoking the Java program directly?  You need to use `java --jar {java program name}` instead of just specifying the name of the Java program.

Comment: This script came with the GlassFish server, and has worked for many, many, many people unmodified, so the commands in it are flawless. Except for a reliance on certain files to be in a certain relation with `dirname $0`.

Comment: @tbodt: and `dirname $0` when you run your script as `/usr/bin/asadmin` is?

Comment: @gnp it won't even run

Comment: @tbodt: What I mean is that `dirname $0` for `/usr/bin/asadmin` is `/usr/bin`. Paraphrasing you: it relies on certain files to bi in `/usr/bin`. Are they there? Better yet: does the script run on it's original path?